# $\epsilon$ sum doubt

Tags: measure-theory, arithmetic

[image]

How do we have $\sum_\limits{n\in\mathbb{Z}}^{}\frac{1}{3}.\frac{\epsilon}{2^{|n|}}=\frac{1}{3}\epsilon+2\sum_\limits{n\in\mathbb{N}}^{}\frac{1}{3}.\frac{\epsilon}{2^{|n|}}$? I understand $2\sum_\limits{n\in\mathbb{N}}^{}\frac{1}{3}$ is due to the fact $n\in\mathbb{N}$ instead of $n\in\mathbb{Z}$, however it is weird to think of an index with negative numbers. I do not understand where comes the $\frac{1}{3}\epsilon$ from.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps it is more clear written this way:

$$\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{3}\frac{\epsilon}{2^{|n|}}=\frac{1}{3}\frac{\epsilon}{2^{0}}+2\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{3}\frac{\epsilon}{2^{n}}$$

Here, the author is using the convention that $\mathbb{N}$ does not include zero. Note that there is no ambiguity in defining a sum that runs over $\mathbb{Z}$ since the summand is nonnegative.